# How to match a an exact piece of string with full stop in MySQL Full text search?

Tags: mysql, sql, scala, full-text-search

I have a table "employee" in Mysql, I decide to use FULL TEXT SEARCH INDEX for this.

employee table has a name column and values are like this

```
'ramakrishna',
'ramakrishna.hande',
'Ramakrishna.Hande',
'hande'
```

Now I want to write a query which fetches me 'ramakrishna.hande' and 'Ramakrishna.Hande'.

I wrote

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST("ramakrishna.hande");
```

But it fetches me everything  from above list. I want to avoid this . I am using Scala as the programming language which I am using for executing MySQL query.

Is there a way to solve it ?

Comment: I'm confused.  One part of your question says that you are using Scala.  Another says you are using MySQL.  Please elaborate.

Comment: I am using Scala code to execute MySQL queries. Thats what I meant

Comment: @user9920500 Please,  specify Scala code which you are using to execute SQL query.

Comment: I meant, I am using  JDBC with scala for above query. The problem lies with limitations of FULL TEXT SEARCH. So I wanted to know if it can be solved

Comment: Why not `SELECT * FROM employee WHERE LOWER(name) = "ramakrishna.hande";`